# Some .jpg images fail to open on iOS

Tags: ios, graphics

I'm trying to open and/or save the images from The *Language Atlas of the Pacific Area* (http://ecai.org/austronesiaweb/PacificAtlasImageMaps.htm) and meet a strange effect: the smallest and, seemingly, noncomplicated pictures fail on iOS. An example of one is: http://ecai.berkeley.edu/austronesiaweb/maps/pacificatlas/Pacific_legends/L026G.jpg . It's just 415x443 pixels, trivially opened on PC, but any attempt (direct open, downloading, sending myself through e-mail) leads to unreadable file.

If I just copy and paste the file into arbitrary graphic editor and save, again as JPG, the resulting file opens. What's the matter with this particular file?

Comment: Link comes up as a broken image on Mac.

Comment: Link works on Firefox and vivaldi but not Safari on mac. With the last sentance of the question is looks like the jpg file is corrupt or webkit has a bug

Comment: Also opens in Chrome.